# Auto background color is black even when I create a new Activity

Tags: android, xml

I don't know if is related with git but after committing my project using git, every Activity's background color is changed even when I create a new Activity.

Why?

My style file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></style>
</resources>
```

Comment: commit won't change anything in your code.Pull might may update your code.Just check your style.xml file or just post it here

Comment: uploaded my style file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>
```

I changed "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".
It is worked.Thanks everyone....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake you are using dark theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textColor</item>
```

Comment: it is used for tool bar style only.But i changed AppCompat.ActionBar,still don't work